# Ajax to call another Ajax function upon done

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

```
var App = {
actionRequest: function (url,data,callback){
    var that = this;
    $('#menu').panel('close');
    $.mobile.loading('show');
    $.when(

        $.ajax({
            method: 'POST',
            url: url + '?' + new Date().getTime(),
            data: data
        })            

    ).done(function(data,html) {        
            that.refreshCart();
            $.mobile.loading('hide');               
        }

    );
}

refreshCart: function(){        
    App.loadExternalContent('content','scripts/data_ajax.php','action=getCart','templates/cart.htm');
    }
}
```

I need to call refreshCart in ".done". How can i write a callback function in ".done" to do so? Sorry i am new with Ajax.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
var object = {
  actionRequest: function(url, data, callback) {
    $('#menu').panel('close');
    $.mobile.loading('show');
    $.ajax({
      method: 'POST',
      url: url + '?' + new Date().getTime(),
      data: data
    }).done(function(data, html) {
        if ($.isFunction(callback)) {
          callback();
        }
        $.mobile.loading('hide');
      }
    );
  }
}
```

usage:

if `refreshCart` is function in the object you can also do this:

```
var object = {
    actionRequest: function(url, data, callback) {
      var that = this;

      $('#menu').panel('close');
      $.mobile.loading('show');
      $.ajax({
            method: 'POST',
            url: url + '?' + new Date().getTime(),
            data: data
          }).done(function(data, html) {
              // without using a callback
              that.refreshCart();
              $.mobile.loading('hide');
            }

          );
        },
        refreshCart: function() {
          App.loadExternalContent('content', 'scripts/data_ajax.php', 'action=getCart', 'templates/cart.htm');
        }
    }
```

Here is an example of how to use ajax requests

```js
$.ajax({
    url: 'http://echo.jsontest.com/title/ipsum/content/blah',
    method: 'GET'
  })
  .done(function(response) {
    console.log(response);
  })
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: I will need to call this function refreshCart. is it possible?

Comment: of course it is you just pass `refreshCart` as a function, or look at my alternative, you dont need to pass the function as a callback

Comment: I put an alert in the .done function 
alert('test'); 
but the alert is not working.

Comment: look at the update, the .done function is now correct

Comment: @NicholasChew I included an example in the answer

Comment: i think you missed a closing bracket before the .done

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/123792/discussion-between-walksaway-and-nicholas-chew).

Comment: @NicholasChew yes i did on the 2nd example, updated :)

Answer (score 1):

I am assuming you are referring this code in class.

```
actionRequest: function (url,data,callback){
    var self = this;  //keep reference of current instance for more info read closures in JS
    $('#menu').panel('close');
    $.mobile.loading('show');
    $.when(

        $.ajax({
            method: 'POST',
            url: url + '?' + new Date().getTime(),
            data: data
        })            

    ).done(function(data,html) {        
            self.refreshCart(); 
            $.mobile.loading('hide');               
        }

    );
}

refreshCart: function(){        
    App.loadExternalContent('content','scripts/data_ajax.php','action=getCart','templates/cart.htm');
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Ajax function:

```
actionRequest: function (url,data,callback){
    $('#menu').panel('close');
    $.mobile.loading('show');
    $.when(

        $.ajax({
            method: 'POST',
            url: url + '?' + new Date().getTime(),
            data: data
        })            

    ).done(function(data,html) {        
            callback();
            $.mobile.loading('hide');               
        }

    );
}
```

call function:

```
actionRequest(url, data, refreshCart);
```